# Scrolling and resizing with ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a problem with ExtJs sizes and scrolling. Here is a simple example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ucd

```js
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var win = new Ext.Window({
        id: 'win',
        layout: 'fit',
        closable: true,
        bodyPadding: 5,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: {
            xtype: "form",
            defaultAnchor: "100%",
            items: [{
                xtype: "panel",
                layout: "fit",
                overflowY: "scroll",
                //overflowY: "auto", 
                layout: 'hbox',
                items: [{
                    xtype: "fieldset",
                    margin: 5,
                    padding: 5,
                    labelWidth: 140,
                    defaultAnchor: "100%",
                    collapsible: true,
                    title: "groupbox",
                    items: [{
                        itemId: "SNAME",
                        xtype: "textfield",
                        margin: 5,
                        fieldLabel: "Name:",
                    }],
                }],
            }]
        }
    });
    
    win.show();
});
```

Problem:

1. It's a side issue. I don't understand, why `overflowY: 'auto'` won't work. It works in my local project, and in this Fiddle scrolling behaves as hidden. May I be need to call doLayout() or something on resize event. So I did `overflow: "scroll"`.
2. You can see that ExtJs doesn't leave place for the scrollbar and it cover the fieldset. Why? How resolve this?
3. In my local project `overflow: 'auto'` works. And scrollbars always appears, because innerct panel div have same size as body div panel. So scrolling behaves as on set `overflow: 'scroll'`. And fieldset right border is hidden by scroll.

Answer (score 1):

You are way overnesting. You are putting a container in a container in a container and all with there own layout calculations. Besides that your dom (which is always expensive to render) is way to big, the layout manager of ExtJs is way to busy and I can't tell what is going wrong because all of this.

Take a look at this code. It has exactly the same result, is much cleaner and your dom is much smaller.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    new Ext.form.Panel({
        id: 'form',
        closable: true,
        floating: true,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        width: 500,
        items: [{
            xtype: "fieldset",
            padding: 5,
            labelWidth: 140,
            layout: 'anchor',
            defaults: {
                xtype: "textfield",
                anchor: '100%',
                margin: 5
            },
            collapsible: true,
            title: "groupbox",
            items: [{
                name: "SNAME",
                fieldLabel: "Name:"
            }]
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my task to implement the input structure, I do not have to do with its development and I can not throw items deems unnecessary.